# Can I verify a phone number using firebase and react-native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to make an app which needs a phone number verification. Is this possible?

I tried to use digits but it's not longer available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Firebase [phone number authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth) is the replacement to Digits, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/digits-web).

Answer (score 2):

Use Twilio to send veryfication SMS to user provided phone number, or use [Facebook Account Kit](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit), which among other methods offers verification by phone number. And it's free.